# How to change the size and type of font of \replacecmpd in chemnum 1.0

Tags: chemnum

First of all I am new to asking questions here.

Second, I am writing a document where I need to import an `.eps` file to have my scheme. My document is set to use `Times New Roman` at `12pt`, but I want the labels of the schemes to be `Times New Roman` at `10pt`. I was using `bpchem` to keep track of the numbering using `chemstyle`, however I need to have `chapter`s and the structures in chapter one should be numbered as `1.XXX` and for chapter two `2.XXX` and so on for the next chapters, so I changed to `chemnum`. With `chemstyle` it was as easy as adding in the preamble `\renewcommand*{\schemerefformat}{\fontsize{10}{12}}`, but I have no idea how to do change the font type to `Times New Roman` `10pt` only for the EPS files, while keeping `Times New Roman` `12pt` in the rest of the document. Can anybody help me? This is the link for DA

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0nmvt84yuzke5rq/DA.eps

and this is the one for DA2

https://www.dropbox.com/s/sg2qwmrsaytsuqv/DA2.eps

Thanks in advance.

I hope this is a good minimal working example

```
\documentclass[onehalfspacing,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tgtermes} %sets font to Times New Roman
\usepackage[format=hang,labelfont={bf},margin=1em,labelsep=period,textformat=period]{caption}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{bpchem}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{chemstyle}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\makeatletter
\newcmpdcounterformat{chapter}{\thechapter.\@arabic} %this adds the chapter number to the structure numbering
\makeatother
\setchemnum{
  replace-style = \rmfamily ,
  counter-within = chapter ,
  counter-format = chapter % use new counter format
}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter1}

This is just an example of a Diels Alder (DA) rxn, you need a diene (\refcmpd{Diene}) and a dienophile (\refcmpd{Dienophile}) to produce a cyclohexene derivative such as \refcmpd{DAadduct}.

 \begin{scheme}[!h]
    \replacecmpd{Diene}
    \replacecmpd{Dienophile}
    \replacecmpd{DAadduct}
    \includegraphics{DA}
    \caption{A DA run not likely to take place}
    \label{fig:DA}
  \end{scheme}

  \chapeter{Chapter2}

  To have a successful DA rxn, one must have an electron deficient diene (\refcmpd{EDdiene}) and an electron rich dienophile (\refcmpd{ERdienophile}) to successfully generate a cyclohexene derivative, in this case \refcmpd{Daadduct.a}

   \begin{scheme}[!h]
    \replacecmpd{EDdiene}
    \replacecmpd{ERdienophile}
    \replacecmpd{DAadduct.a}
    \includegraphics{DA2}
    \caption{A DA run very likely to take place}
    \label{fig:DA2}
  \end{scheme}

  This was just an example.

  \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Does `replace-style = \fontsize{10}{12}\rmfamily,` help?

Comment: It worked like a charm, I was adding a comma between \fontsize{10} and \rmfamily!! Thank you so so much!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
replace-style = \fontsize{10}{12}\rmfamily,
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[onehalfspacing,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tgtermes} %sets font to Times New Roman
\usepackage[format=hang,labelfont={bf},margin=1em,labelsep=period,textformat=period]{caption}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{bpchem}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{chemstyle}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\makeatletter
\newcmpdcounterformat{chapter}{\thechapter.\@arabic} %this adds the chapter number to the structure numbering
\makeatother
\setchemnum{
  replace-style = \fontsize{10}{12}\rmfamily,
  counter-within = chapter ,
  counter-format = chapter % use new counter format
}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter1}

This is just an example of a Diels Alder (DA) rxn, you need a diene (\refcmpd{Diene}) and a dienophile (\refcmpd{Dienophile}) to produce a cyclohexene derivative such as \refcmpd{DAadduct}.

 \begin{scheme}[!h]
    \replacecmpd{Diene}
    \replacecmpd{Dienophile}
    \replacecmpd{DAadduct}
    \includegraphics{DA}
    \caption{A DA run not likely to take place}
    \label{fig:DA}
  \end{scheme}

  \chapter{Chapter2}

  To have a successful DA rxn, one must have an electron deficient diene (\refcmpd{EDdiene}) and an electron rich dienophile (\refcmpd{ERdienophile}) to successfully generate a cyclohexene derivative, in this case \refcmpd{Daadduct.a}

   \begin{scheme}[!h]
    \replacecmpd{EDdiene}
    \replacecmpd{ERdienophile}
    \replacecmpd{DAadduct.a}
    \includegraphics{DA2}
    \caption{A DA run very likely to take place}
    \label{fig:DA2}
  \end{scheme}

  This was just an example.

  \end{document}
```

[image]